# How to efficiently retrieve 2 million records from a DB2 database using Java?

Tags: jdbc, db2, large-data

I need to retrieve and process around 2 million records from a Db2 database using Java. We are migrating tables from one db to another and so i am trying to do a diff between two tables to check if there is any difference in the data.

Currently i am doing a normal query and getting the data into the resultset and processing it using HashMap's. But its taking forever to process. I did try setting the fetchsize to a decent value(200), but this didn't help either.

Is there any other better way of retrieving the data like getting in chunks and process it?

Comment: What does your query look like? And yes, you could presumably parallelize this (e.g. [IBM PureData](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/puredata/) or [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) or [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)).

Comment: I am doing a "select *" with a join in it. I added a timestamp log before and after executing the result set. As i see its taking 3 secs to get the data into the resultset.But i am appending each column value of every row and making it as a key to insert into the hashmap. I am checking in target hashmap for the sourcekey and viceversa, removing the key if a match is found. There by i will end up with data which is diff. It worked fine for 500K records.

Comment: Do you know where your bottleneck is? Did you profile your program execution? Generally speaking, the most efficient way to process 2 million records is to **not** retrieve them but process them in the database instead, e.g. by setting up federation between the two databases.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to accomplish the goal of "Check if there is any difference in the data" would be to export the data from both tables in the same format, and use your favorite file DIFF program.

In the windows environment I typically use Notepad++ or Windiff to accomplish that.

If you can't use that strategy, comparing them within the database engine would be a close second choice.  Create a copy of the table in the new database, and write a simple SQL script to search for DIFFs for you.  I like to do that with a full outer join, returning rows where one or the other side is null.

```
select a.*, b.*
from a 
full outer join b
on a.key1 = b.key1
and a.otherkeys = b.otherkeys
where a.key1 is null 
   or b.key1 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Export function/batch (jaxb) from old db 
-> create a XML file(s) -> 
Import function/batch (hibernate) from XML(s) to new db